# Close button is no longer visible in “toast” notifications and error messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, error-message, cdn

When I've got 5 or fewer up / down votes left for the day, I get a message informing me of this. Although the dialog will disappear after a while, there has also previously been (during the many times I encountered this over the past couple of years) a close button on the right side, which I usually used to get the dialog to go away more quickly. However, today, that option is not visible any more, as shown below:

---

[image: Message showing 4 votes left, but with no close button.]

---

Nonetheless, I found that when I hover my mouse over where the button used to be, an outline of it appears, and clicking there does close the dialog. I realize this is quite a minor issue, but was this dialog changed on purpose and, if so, is there any particular reason why this was done?

Note I'm using Microsoft Edge 84.0.522.61 on Windows 10, with no recent updates of the browser since the last time when the warning message appeared as it normally did before.

**Update:** [Sebastian Simon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/289905/sebastian-simon)'s comments give more details, such as other places where the same issue seems to occur, e.g., this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359862/close-button-is-no-longer-visible-in-toast-notifications-and-error-messages#comment1201163_359862) about the ">" no longer showing in the "Flagging > Closing" header text.

Comment: This applies to all such messages, currently, not just the “x votes left” one.

Comment: The inner SVG in the button looks just like `<svg class="svg-skeleton-element-during-loading m0"></svg>`. That first class name makes it `display: none !important;`. `GET`
`https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/ClearSm.svg?v=5acef7872715` is being blocked due to _“CORS Missing Allow Origin”_, or missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header, as the console says. It’s strange that `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js` requests keep working fine, though. Maybe an issue related to MIME types?

Comment: This issue is also causing the right arrow to be missing from the Flag / Close dialog breadcrumb header. It [used to show something like “Flagging › Closing”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/400616/4642212), but [now it’s showing “FlaggingClosing”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2Bkd.png) because the SVG arrow at `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/ArrowRightAltSm.svg?v=5acef7872715` can’t be fetched.

Comment: Strangely, it works fine on MSE, as MSE actually requests `https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Img/stacks-icons/ArrowRightAltSm.svg?v=5acef7872715`, but a different site, such as Super User, requests `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/ArrowRightAltSm.svg?v=5acef7872715`. The `meta.stackexchange.com` domain works, `cdn.sstatic.net` doesn’t. However, `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27` still works! Is it because `sprites.svg` has an `xmlns` attribute and `cdn.sstatic.net` is picky about this document type? None of the SVGs have an XML declaration, though…

Comment: And another place where this is an issue: the `i` help icon when editing tags is completely gone; not even the link is there anymore. URL is `https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/stacks-icons/HelpSm.svg?v=5acef7872715`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thanks for the edit and the extra details in your comments. I've updated my post to specifically mention your helpful comments.

Comment: Now also reported on MSO: [The button to dismiss the "This post has been deleted." banner in review is not visible until hovered over](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404726/4642212).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

SVG icons recently moved from `/img/svg-icons` to `/img/stacks-icons` and we overlooked updating the CORS policy along with it. The issue should be resolved now, though you might have to "empty cache and hard reload" in the Chrome parlance.